# Match two values in a collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have two values I need to match as you can see in the picture below: [image]

I tried something like this:

```
 const index = state.locks.users.findIndex(
  stateUser => stateUser._id === action.payload.customerPayload.accessid
```

But I’m getting the error:

> findIndex of undefined.

And I guess that’s because of locks being an array.

But I’m really uncertain how to fix this issue. Should I have multiple findIndexes? One for the lock and one for to match the users?

Thanks for reading my post. And I appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: Can you post the code that gives the error on `findIndex`?

Comment: `locks` is an array. You need to iterate over it before accessing `users`

Comment: @Halcyon the snippet above is that code. Thanks

Comment: @nilobarp are you suggesting I should wrap it with a for loop and then use the increments number as the index for locks?

Comment: Just to get it straight, locks is an array of users? Or is locks an array of objects which have a member array of users?

Comment: @ronenmiller locks is an array that contains objects. And inside of each lock there’s an array called users. And I need to match the _id from an user to customerPayloads accessId.

Comment: So are the users arrays the same in all locks? Otherwise if you get an index how would you know which lock it belongs to? Why not simply return the object?

Comment: @ronenmiller no the data varies, but the structure is the same. I guess I won’t know that..

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet should be

```
let itemIndex = -1;

state.locks.map((lock) => {
    lock.users.findIndex(...)
});
```

Assuming `state` is an object containing `locks` array.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to help me. Will try your solution when I come home. But why are you creating a variable and assigning -1 to it?

Comment: This way, when map is done you will have an index. But this does not say which lock you are referring to, so this is only good if all users arrays are the same for all locks.

Comment: @MartinNordström we start with the premise that the item we are searching for is not in the array. Since array indices starts from `0`, `-1` is an invalid index indicating non-existent element.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you is do a double for loop (as you've already figured) to get the user object that you need.

Consider the following snippet (adjust to your data structure):

```
let state = {
    locks: [
        {
            users: [
                { _id: '123' },
                { _id: '456' }
            ]
        },
        {
            users: [
                { _id: '678' },
                { _id: '789' }
            ]
        },
    ]
};

function getUserObjByID(stateObj, userID) {
    for (let usersObject of state.locks) {
        for (let user of usersObject.users) {
            if (user._id === userID) {
                return user;
            }
        }

    }
}

let myObj = getUserObjByID(state, '678');
console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

So it works now. What I had to do with my reducer was this:

```
case 'REMOVE_USER':
  return {
    ...state,
    locks: state.locks.map(lock => {
      return {
        ...lock,
        users: lock.users
          ? lock.users.filter(
              user => user._id != action.payload.customerPayload.accessid
            )
          : []
      }
    })
  }
```